# Limit the amount of entries a user can post?

Tags: channel-entries

Is it possible to limit the amount of entries that a user can post. For example, if users are posting entries to a channel via a safecracker form, can I limit them to a single entry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How would you want to enforce the limit? You could use a query tag at the top of the Safecracker form:

```
{exp:query sql="Select count(*) 'number_posts' from exp_channel_titles where author_id='{member_id}'"}
    {if number_posts == 1}{/if}
{/exp:query}
```

And within that query, you could do a redirect, display a message, or wrap the whole form in a conditional that wouldn't display it if the user had > 1 result.

You could also only enable the form `if number_posts < 1`, and then in the else case redirect to an edit form for their single entry.

(Might not be the right syntax for author/member -- You'll need to look up the actual tags for those.)

Comment: I'll save you the trouble of looking it up. ;) See [`total_entries`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html#total-entries)